# How and why is Rise/Run gives the inclination of the line (or slope)?

Tags: slope

How and why is Rise/Run gives the inclination of the line (or slope)?
How to understand the theoratical concept behind it ?

Comment: $\frac{\text{rise}}{\text{run}}$ can be thought of as $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ which is the the change in $y$ for each unit increase in $x$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Let's say you're walking uphill. If you move 5 meters vertically for every 3 meters that you move horizontally, then the path you're walking on is very steep. On the other hand, if you move 1 meter vertically for every 3 meters that you move horizontally, the path you're walking on is much less steep. The "grade" (steepness) of roads is measured like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grade_(slope)

Answer (score 3):

It's a definition. We *define* the slope to be the rise over the run. This way a positive slope is a higher number when it's steeper, which is nice. But we could very well have defined it as "run" over "rise".